# save alsamixer input source centos 6

Tags: linux, audio, centos, microphone, alsa

I am not able to save the input source of my alsamixer. Every time I reboot the system the input source is set back to front mic. I want it to stay as rear mic.

I tried

```
alsactl store
```

I disabled the following in my /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
### Automatically restore the volume of streams and devices
#load-module module-device-restore
#load-module module-stream-restore
#load-module module-card-restore
```

I am using Centos 6.4 64 Bit

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 64 bit user, I've the same problem.